# Getting jar specific path as string

Tags: java, jar, io, filereader

My package structure is as follows :
src/xxx/
src/yyy/

I have a class in the package src/xxx/ lets call it `classA.java` and I need to get the path of src/yyy/ how can I do it ? I tried

```
String s = classA.class.getResourcesAsStream("/yyy/").toString();
```

but it didn't work..
I need it as a `String` because I making a new `FileReader` with that path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's somewhat unclear to me what you're trying to do. But if the file is within a jar file, `FileReader` isn't going to work anyway - you don't *have* a file as far as the operating system is concerned. You should just use `getResourceAsStream`, and then wrap the `InputStream` in an `InputStreamReader`. That way you can also specify a character encoding - even when I *am* using a file, I use `FileInputStream` and `InputStreamReader` for that reason.

So you want something like:

```
try (Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(
         ClassA.class.getResourceAsStream("foo.txt"),
         StandardCharsets.UF_8)) { // Or whichever encoding is appropriate
    // Read from the reader
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adapt below code to use FileReader

```
public class Demo 
{
public static void main( String[] args ) {

    ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();

    InputStream is = cl.getResourceAsStream("yyy/FILENAME");
    if (is != null) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        try {
            System.out.println(reader.readLine());
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Your first sentence makes no sense - why would you suggest using `FileReader` when it won't work? (Also the exception handling is awful, you don't specify a character encoding, and you don't close the stream, but those are slightly aside from the main point.)

Comment: @Jon Steek ` those are slightly aside from the main point` - thats the point. The OP should put in some effort as well

Comment: So you're creating *deliberately* awful code? I don't see how that's helpful to the many readers who will see this in the future. Oh, and there's no obvious reason to use a context classloader here.

Comment: (And my point about the first sentence still stands, too - the key to this question IMO is that if there isn't a file in the normal file system sense, `FileReader` simply isn't going to work.)

Comment: could you explain me what is ClassLoader